# how do I get contents from page updated by ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, browser

I'm using a `WebBrowser` in my application. When I click on submit button, some javascript runs and by using ajax the page get some new contentes that I want to save. But it doesn't work, if I do:

```
btn.InvokeMember("click"); // send the form and then runs AJAX
Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10); // it doesn't take so long... but about 1000
var d = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p"); // p is null
```

but if I call `var d = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("p");` from a button click it works (`p` isn't `null`) even if I remove `Thread.Sleep(1000 * 10);`

I have no idea why. It is not because the `p` HTML tags wasn't loaded yet because the click on the button even without the `Thread.Sleep()` call take much less time but I get the HTML elements.

I hope this is clear but if it isn't tell me and I'll try clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `timer` instead of `sleep` and check browser. `ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`